# Prove that a set in $\mathbb R^3$ is not an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to prove that the set $\{(\cos(t),\sin(t),t)\in A^3(\mathbb R); t\in \mathbb R \}$ is not an algebraic set.

I already proved that the set $\{(\sin(t),t)\in A^2(\mathbb R);t\in \mathbb R \}$ is not algebraic but the method that I used doesn't seems to be general.

Comment: What was your method for that set?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Bezout's theorem?

Comment: Can't you choose a line that intersects the curve at infinitely many points? I know the affine line has the cofinite topology, I believe so does every dimension 1 variety. I've only briefly considered this problem before, so I'm not sure

Comment: I'm not allowed to use it

Answer (score 4):

Let $X=(cos(t),sin(t),t)$ Consider the plan $P$ defined by $(x,y,z): x=0$, $X\cap P=(0,(-1)^k,\pi/2+k\pi), k\in Z$ is not algebraic, thus $X$ is not algebraic.

Comment: Oh, that was really simple, but how do you prove that $X\cap P$ is not algebraic?

Comment: An infinite number of discrete points is not algebraic

Comment: but how do you prove that? sorry if my question is basic, but i don't know how to prove that

Comment: Try to read about the decomposition of an algebraic set in irreducible components which are finite when the set is Noetherian, look for example Hartshorne or any other books

Comment: @TsemoAristide This is because a polynomial over a field (in your case is infinite number of discrete points) can have finitely many roots, so it is an union of infinitely many algebraic sets. This violate the finite union of algebraic sets is an algebraic set. (fundamental proposition in algebraic geometry)

Answer (score 0):

I'll prove that the Zariski closure $W$ of the helix $H$ is the unit cylinder $V$. Take any line parallel to the $z$-axis on the cylinder. It intersects $H$ infinitely often. We can write $I(W)=(F_1,\dots,F_r)$ or $W=\bigcap\limits_i V(F_i)$. Each $F_i$ must vanish on $H$ and hence on $L\cap H$. But since $F_i$ vanishes infinitely often on a line $L$, it must vanish identically on $L$. Thus $L\subset V(F_i)$ for all $i$. Thus $L\subset W$. Since this holds for an arbitrary line L, and V is the union of all such lines, $V\subset W$. Thus $V=W$.